# Dual power supply with two boost converters

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, dual, buck-boost

I currently have a dual power supply, that supplies +/-15V. One -output of the PS is connected to the other channel's +output (GND). Now, the problem is that I need +/-50V. I bought two step-up boost converters (cheap ones from Amazon), but now I realise that I may have the wrong idea. The converters have +/- input and +/- output, and I connected the +15V from the PS into the +input of one, and -15V into the -input of the other. The unconnected inputs are grounded. Now, my idea was that one of them would give +50V (which it does), and the other -50V. Note that my +converter has its -input and -output grounded, my -converter has its +input and +output grounded.

However, the -50V is not working, and the PS keeps getting current locked. Am I connecting things wrong, or is my idea wrong?

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusing explanation. Here is a rough sketch of what I'm trying to do:

[image: connection diagram]

([Source](https://ibb.co/fxRu09))

I am using this to power a high voltage op-amp, specifically OPA454.

I'm not sure what "isolated" boost converter, but I have two of these from Amazon:

[DROK Micro DC Converter Power Transformer 120W 12V/24V/48V 10-32V to 35-60V Volt Regulator Module Boost Step-up Inverter Board DIY for Car Auto Vehicle Motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011KL30TU)

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I followed this for a while, then got lost in all the hand waving.  Show a diagram.  Starting the process to close as *unclear*, so hurry.  The clock is ticking.  A link to the datasheet of these 50 V modules would help.  It is important to know whether they are isolated or not.

Comment: they must be isolated for V- use.

Comment: Looks like it is not isolated so the in- = out-

Comment: No. Look into the schematic of the boost converter or a gerneric boost converter. Ground wire runs from input to output so you have no galvanic isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit cannot ever work. The modules provide a regulated voltage between the output terminal and -ve lead of the power convertor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDdK94.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You would need to have the lower DC-DC convertor be an isolated module (no connection from input to output) to make this work.

One other way to do this is to get a Boost convertor that supplies 100V output and use an electronic ground (rail splitter circuit). I've used a bunch of [these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-900W-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-8-60V-to-10-120V-15A-Step-Up-Power-Supply-Module/322724801210) to provide 75V for stepper motors ...but they extend to 120V. You could use 30V input to reduce the input current requirement.

Comment: Another solution is to replace the lower boost converter with a non-isolated buck converter and disconnect it from the -15V input.  This configuration makes the buck converter an inverting boost converter.  In the OP's case it does require a converter with an input range of 15-65V and an output range that includes 50V at 65Vin, and it will require a substantial amount of current to start up, but it does work.

Comment: Actually, neither needs to be *isolated*.  But the task does require one converter which passes the negative input through unswitched, and another which passed the positive rail through unswitched.  Both varieties do exist (found a single-cell phone charger booster than connected the high side through...).  But of course one single unisolated design cannot fulfill both roles.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.  I think your circuit can work with one minor modification...remove the connection between the +/-15V supply.

You don't mention where you're getting +/-15 from, but if it's a bench supply, 
the outputs are usually isolated unless you connect or ground them externally.  Your -50V supply is probably trying to generate 50V over a common ground between its negative input and its negative output.

If you're using a dual supply with a common ground, you may need an additional one--and they have to be isolated from each other, which means isolated from any common inputs as well.  Compared to your output ground, the -15 supply will be providing -50V on its negative terminal, and -35V on the positive.

Answer (score 0):

Note that after clicking on *Product Details* you get a bullet list of features.  Near the top, it clearly says "non-isolated".  That means the negative of the power input is internally connected to the negative of the power output.

For your circuit to work, the modules would have to be *isolated*.  That means there is no direct connection between input and output.  The output can float (within some range, usually a few 100 V at least) with respect to the input.  With such modules, you could power two of them from the same 15 V supply, but connect their outputs to make a ±50 V supply with ground.

In your case, you say that your ±15 V supplies are really separate (apparently isolated) supplies, and you connected them together to make a ±15 V supply with ground.  Don't do that.  Leave them unconnected, and have each power one converter.

However, the real answer is probably to get two *isolated* 50 V supplies that can run directly off of whatever is powering the 15 V supplies.  It seems silly to use 15 V supplies only to power 50 V supplies.  Make 50 V directly, if that's what you ultimately want.

Comment: "Non-isolated" means that *something* is connected through, but *not necessarily the negative* rail.  I recall trying to use a single-cell phone charge booster in a dual-voltage project, only to discover that what was common was its *positive* rail.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but in the case of the OP's 50 V modules, the documentation is rather slim.  If it's not explicitly stated, it would be very very unusual to have anything other than the two grounds connected.